# Cycle through windows with keyboard in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: keyboard, pdf

I use Adobe Acrobat Pro a lot, and often keep multiple documents open. Does anyone know of a way of cycling through the open windows of this application without resorting to the mouse?

(Cmd+` (backtick) does not work.)

I use OS X 10.6.4 on a 13" MacBook Pro.

Comment: I think it's bug, and there is no other short key except what you said (cmd + `)

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of expecting that, however, I find it slightly odd that there is no way (apparently) to cycle through all open windows in the OS, irregardless of which application has opened them.

Comment: Is there a menu in Adobe Acrobat Pro to do so? If this is the case, you can define your own shortcut in Preference Pane > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts

Answer (score 3):

You can try <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>. It's working on both Mac OS & PC.

Comment: Indeed the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> answer from Jayaprakash above works in my Mac, OS X Version 10.8.2.

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to cycling through all open windows in *all* apps, or all open windows within Adobe Acrobat?

If the former, use <kbd>⌘tab</kbd> to switch between apps, and then <kbd>⌘`</kbd> to swap between windows in that app.

If the latter, <kbd>⌘`</kbd> works just fine for me (Adobe Acrobat Pro 9.3.4; 15" MacBook Pro running OS X 10.6.4; no particular third-party addons that might change this behavior).

Comment: Hmm, maybe it is just a bug in my version of Acrobat (9.3.2), I'll see if I can upgrade it.

Answer (score 2):

I had given up on this for a long time, but trying it once more I noticed that the "`" requires to be pressed for longer for the switch to happen. Once it switches you have to let go quickly or it will switch back to the 1st document.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Witch (http://manytricks.com/witch/). It'll give you many more options for how you can cycle through windows and open apps. It's not free ($19), but there is a free trial.

Answer (score 0):

option+command+backslash (on french keyboard) (`, on english probably)

Answer (score -1):

On Mac OS X 10.11.1 with Acrobat Pro DC installed try <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>.